# What happens if a creature with a Bag of Holding is polymorphed/wild-shaped, then is placed inside another Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wild-shape, polymorph

If a druid who has a bag of holding uses Wild Shape to become a bug, then the bag of holding merges with their new form (and is not dropped). Then someone puts said bug in another bag of holding, what happens?

What if the druid were polymorphed instead?

Answer (score 12):

## RAW is unclear, so this would be up to your DM

This is the sort of outside case that the rules do not cover, and thus such an occurrence would fall to your DM to make a ruling on.

For example, I would likely rule that nothing happens because, whilst merged with the druid, the bag of holding isn't really a bag of holding anymore, it's now part of a bug.

If the druid in bug form leaves the other bag of holding before reverting to original form, no problem. But what if the druid reverted to original form inside the other bag of holding? Would the two bags react to each other at that point, or would that only occur if someone tries to take the druid's bag back out of the other bag, or would nothing happen either way (the text does say "Placing a bag of holding *inside* ...", after all)? These are also consequences of such rulings that the DM would need to rule on should they come up in play.