# Can you use Wild Shape to meld a Bag of Holding into your Wild Shape form while creatures are inside the Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape

My players are planning a heist. Two of the players each have a Necklace of Adaptation and do not need to breathe. They want to go inside a bag of holding (which is allowed from what I know), then give the bag to the Druid who wild shapes into a rat and chooses to "merge their equipment into their new form". Thus allowing the rat to carry the two PCs into the mansion easy-peasy. This is super creative, but would that be possible?

Comment: *Somewhat* related questions: "[What happens if a creature with a Bag of Holding is polymorphed/wild-shaped, then is placed inside another Bag of Holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170382)" And "[Can a druid use Wild Shape to get rid of a cursed item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174611)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I really like this kind of interesting question, so thanks for posting it. Another user and I have made some minor edits to your question. If we got anything wrong or you see something else you would like to change, you can always [edit] the question. We also have a [help] and a [tour]. Happy gaming!

Comment: Depending on their races and armor, be wary of the 500 pound weight limit! For 2 Humans + normal equip it should be absolutely fine, but if they want 2 battleaxes and full plate each you'll reach the limit rather quickly

Comment: Question about the tag here... This was originally posed with no system specified and responding to comments Alan put in the 5e tag as the game he was playing. That usually is appropriate, but I wonder if it is limiting here. The fact is, the correct answer for 5e is also the correct answer for *every* edition of D&D (with some caveats for bag of holding weight limits--only 200 lbs in 4e).  In addition, it is the correct answer for both editions of Pathfinder. Since we do not want seven versions of the same question, would it be wise to change the tags to dnd and pathfinder?

Comment: They don't need the necklace of adaptation, see my answer here: [Can a target escape a Wild Shaped Portable Hole/Bag of Holding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180363)

Answer (score 25):

**Easy peasy**

As long as the players can fit through the neck of the bag they can exist inside until you're nice enough to let them out, thanks to the necklaces of adaptation.

Even without them, it would still be possible but how long they can hold their breath would then become an issue.

Just don't die because no one else will know to let them out...

I think using Bags of Holding like this is always a great idea. My players have used a BOH to fly team members across chasms, hide them from magically tracking hunters, sneak extra people into a party, etc.

It can subvert a lot of what the DM thinks might be a challenge for the players and turn tricky situations into slight inconveniences so some DMs may place limits on what can be done.

Comment: Definitely watch the weight limit (500 lbs. in 5e), as most characters are probably already over 150 lbs. each, not counting their gear plus whatever else might be in there. Also...make sure neither of them are carrying their own BoH, portable hole, handy haversack, or the like.

Comment: Don't die.  They canot exit by themselves and would be trapped until someone else let them out

Answer (score 12):

### Yes.

Yes, this is possible. Characters may enter a bag of holding, they have solved the potential problem of running out of air, and there is nothing about a bag of holding that would prevent it from merging with the druid's wild shape form like any other magical item or piece of equipment.

I would carefully track the weight of the two characters going into the bag to make sure they do not exceed the limit, but apart from that limitation, the plan seems solid.

Perhaps they're rendering moot some hard work you did on the mansion exterior and defenses, but this is a fun and creative idea that shows your players are engaged and having fun. This should be encouraged.

**As a side note:** this answer is valid in *every* edition of D&D and in Pathfinder 1e and 2e, as well. There may be some limitations with the Bag of Holding's capacity from edition to edition--it is only 200 pounds in D&D 4e, though Handy Haversqack holds 1,000--but as long as the weight limit is not exceeded, this plan is feasible in every edition plus both Pathfinder editions.

Comment: I’m not sure how the information from other editions and games is relevant.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I believe the answer was written when the specific edition that the question was talking about was unclear; though now it has been clarified so this answer should match that change by restricting itself to the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons

Comment: Yes, the question originally did not specify the edition. It was edited since my answer was posted and now I have been able to correct it. Hopefully that clears up the negative reception I was getting.

Comment: You don’t do much in the way of explaining why it’s possible or how the rules work to permit this. You just say “yes” and then explain how it would play out. This seems like half way to a decent answer.

Comment: My second sentence explains why it is possible.  The rules allow PCs to enter a bag of holding; the PCs have found a way not to run out of air; there is nothing about the bag of holding that would make it an exception to equipment blending into a wild shape. What more do you need, exactly?